# Simple modification of JSON object without serialization gets "cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable"

Tags: json, rust, rustc-serialize

I have a JSON encoded object in Rust 1.6.0. I want to decode it from JSON, change the value of one key, and convert it back to a JSON encoded string again. I don't want to write a struct to hold the data.

I am using rustc_serialize, which mostly seems to be built around serializing structs and automatically doing that, but I just want a simple JSON modification.

`json_contents` is a `String` that has the original, encoded JSON object.

```
let new_value = json::Json::from_str(&format!("[\"http://localhost:{}\"]", port)).unwrap();

let mut myjson_0 = json::Json::from_str(&json_contents).unwrap();
let mut myjson = tilejson_0.as_object().unwrap();
myjson.insert("mykey".to_owned(), new_value);
let new_json: String = json::encode(&myjson).unwrap();
```

However I get the following error:

```
src/main.rs:53:5: 53:13 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*myjson` as mutable
src/main.rs:53     myjson.insert("mykey".to_owned(), new_value);
                   ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I compile this? Is there a better, simpler, JSON Rust library I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging has fixed this problem for me:

I replaced this code:

```
let mut myjson = tilejson_0.as_object().unwrap();
```

With this, to ensure that I had the type that I thought I had:

```
let mut myjson: BTreeMap<String, json::Json> = tilejson_0.as_object().unwrap();
```

and I got this compiler error:

```
src/main.rs:52:54: 52:85 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::btree::map::BTreeMap<collections::string::String, rustc_serialize::json::Json>`,
    found `&collections::btree::map::BTreeMap<collections::string::String, rustc_serialize::json::Json>`
(expected struct `collections::btree::map::BTreeMap`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:52     let mut myjson: BTreeMap<String, json::Json>  tilejson_0.as_object().unwrap();
```

Clearly I was wrong. Rather than an *owned* `BTreeMap`, I had a reference to one, `&BTreeMap`.

The solution was to change the line to this:

```
let mut myjson = tilejson_0.as_object().unwrap().to_owned();
```

And everything compiled and worked (so far)

Comment: you can also use `as_object_mut` to get an `&mut` if you want to modify the original json object.